# Downloading pytorch3d installtion no c++ compiler

Tags: python, c++, pip, pytorch, pytorch3d

I have been trying to download pytorch3d on my PC however it keeps failing. I believe its because of the c++ compiler but I am not sure.

```
FAILED: C:/Users/Virtual Machine/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-fu0xd6su/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-310/Release/Users/Virtual Machine/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-fu0xd6su/pytorch3d/csrc/point_mesh/point_mesh_cpu.obj
      cl /showIncludes /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD /MD /wd4819 /wd4251 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4275 /wd4018 /wd4190 /EHsc "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fu0xd6su\pytorch3d\csrc" "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\include" "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include" "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH" "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC" "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include" "-IC:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include" -c "C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fu0xd6su\pytorch3d\csrc\point_mesh\point_mesh_cpu.cpp" /Fo"C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fu0xd6su\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fu0xd6su\pytorch3d\csrc\point_mesh\point_mesh_cpu.obj" -std=c++14 -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_C -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 /std:c++14
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++14'
      C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/macros/Macros.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cassert': No such file or directory
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.'''
```

Also I am trying to use ninja but I get this error

```
        File "C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 547, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
        File "C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 815, in win_wrap_ninja_compile
          _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
        File "C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1573, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
          _run_ninja_build(
        File "C:\Users\Virtual Machine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1916, in _run_ninja_build
          raise RuntimeError(message) from e
      RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pytorch3d
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have installed?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Did you install VS2019 in a normal way? `<cassert>` is part of the standard library.  It has to be there.

Comment: I am pretty sure I did its been a while since I downloaded it I could try downloading it again